# CSS to target a label that is followed by a div which has a child with invalid input

Tags: css

I have this HTML structure

```css
.sectionLabel {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.25em 1.1em;
  margin: 0 0 .1875em 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #888888;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  color: #FFFF;
  transition: ease .5s;
  position: relative;
  /* ADDING THIS IS REQUIRED */
}

.control:has(:invalid) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label id="mylabel" class="sectionLabel">Section Header</label>
  <div>
      <br>
      <div class="control">
       <label for="nodeName">Node Name</label>
       <input id="nodeName" name="nodeName" pattern="^([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*(\.[A-Za-z0-9_]+)*)+[\.:]([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*)$" value="test" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <button class="submitButton" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Please take a look at: https://jsfiddle.net/e17sgxm2/1/

You will see that an invalid pattern in the text field turns the label red. But I would also like the Section Header to turn red too.

In the actual implementation there are other input fields too. So if any field has an invalid value, I would like the Section Header to turn red.

Comment: FYI, your label appears to wrap multiple inputs. That would be invalid and an accessibility problem.

Comment: Please could you show us what the forms structure actually is? I guess the label is not wrapping the inputs because you have used a + but I can’t be sure. Also, what comes before the label within the form?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, making impossible to tell what your intent is. But yes, you can't nest `:has()` and you should never need to.

Comment: I have made the corrections and also provided a fiddle link for clarity

Comment: CSS Is linear and works in one direction only. Much as there is no parent selector, you can't style something based on subsequent elements,  only preceding elements.

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: Why does this have two close votes for tool/resource recommendation? There is no such request; even the original revision is only related for that after some serious mental gymnastics.

Comment: `form:has(:invalid) .sectionLabel { color: red; }`

Answer (score 1):

**Updated based on comments**

To be more semantically correct we can wrap your elements in a `fieldset`. It would also be more semantically correct to use a `legend` for the `fieldset` but they a awkward to style.

We can use `:has()` on the bounding `fieldset` and work from there

**Updated Solution**

```css
.sectionLabel {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.25em 1.1em;
  margin: 0 0 .1875em 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #888888;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  color: #FFFF;
  transition: ease .5s;
  position: relative;
  /* ADDING THIS IS REQUIRED */
}


/*Adding selector to style the header*/

.control:has(:invalid),
fieldset:has(.control > :invalid)>.sectionLabel {
  color: red;
}


/*normalise fieldset*/

fieldset {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <label id="mylabel" class="sectionLabel">Section Header</label>
    <div class="control">
      <label for="nodeName">Node Name</label>
      <input id="nodeName" name="nodeName" pattern="^([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*(\.[A-Za-z0-9_]+)*)+[\.:]([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*)$" value="test" />
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <button class="submitButton" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Original Answer**
As I mentioned in a comment CSS is linear and works in one direction. You can style something based on preceding elements, but not subsequent elements.

Taking that in mind we can achieve what you want in a somewhat hacky manor by moving the "Section Header" after the content. Then CSS Grid will be used to style it above the content.

However I suspect this may interfere with the reason you have `/* ADDING THIS IS REQUIRED */`. Also this is pretty hacky and I'd probably not actually use this **InTheRealWorld**

```css
form {
  /*Set the form as a grid*/
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-row-gap: 0.5em;
}

.sectionLabel {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.25em 1.1em;
  margin: 0 0 .1875em 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #888888;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  color: #FFFF;
  transition: ease .5s;
  position: relative;
  /* ADDING THIS IS REQUIRED */
  /*Move to the first row of the grid*/
  grid-row-start: 1;  
}

/*Adding selector to the header*/
.control:has(:invalid), div:has(.control > :invalid) + .sectionLabel  {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form>  
  <div>
    <div class="control">
      <label for="nodeName">Node Name</label>
      <input id="nodeName" name="nodeName" pattern="^([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*(\.[A-Za-z0-9_]+)*)+[\.:]([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*)$" value="test" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <label id="mylabel" class="sectionLabel">Section Header</label>
  <button class="submitButton" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot move the Section Header because of the structure of the rest of the form. I guess I may have to resort to javascript

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding a wrapper div around the outer one and then use :has with it to kind of solve the issue.

```css
.sectionLabel {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.25em 1.1em;
  margin: 0 0 .1875em 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #888888;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  color: #FFFF;
  transition: ease .5s;
  position: relative;
  /* ADDING THIS IS REQUIRED */
}

.wrapper:has(:invalid)>.sectionLabel {
  color: red;
}

.control:has(:invalid) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <label id="mylabel" class="sectionLabel">Section Header</label>
    <div>
      <br>
      <div class="control">
        <label for="nodeName">Node Name</label>
        <input id="nodeName" name="nodeName" pattern="^([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*(\.[A-Za-z0-9_]+)*)+[\.:]([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*)$" value="test" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <button class="submitButton" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0y1fp5dv/1/

Comment: Please don't use external code sites like jsfiddle if a Stack Snippet is perfectly fine. Your wrapper div is unnecessary, the form already is a wrapper. `form:has(:invalid) .sectionLabel { color: red; }`

Comment: You are correct. The form can be used. But in my case there are other sectionLabels too and each one has to be targetted separately. Hence the need to have a wrapper.